# My table exceeds the page on both sides

Tags: tables

I'm to make the following table but it exceed the page from both sides and I can't fix it ...   any idea what could be wrong?   Thank you

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[center, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{table}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{0.4\linewidth}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
& \textbf{Words} & \textbf{En words} & \textbf{Gr words} & \textbf{Al words} & \textbf{\% En words} & \textbf{\% Gr words} &\textbf{\% Al words}\\
\hline
\textbf{Gr/En Mixes} & 3663 & 2207 & 1456 & kati & 60,3 & 39,7 & kati\\
\hline
\textbf{Gr/Al/En/ Mixes} & 131 & 48 & 51 & 32 & 36,6 & 38,9 & 24,4\\
\hline
\textbf{Gr/Al Mixes} & 35 & kati & 24 & 11 & kati & 68,6 & 31,4\\
\hline
\textbf{Al/En Mixes} & 131 & 72 & kati & 59 & 55,0 & kati & 45,0\\
\hline
\textbf{Total mixes} & 3960 & 2327 & 1531 & 102 & 58,8 & 38,7 & 2,6\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Table 6: The percentage of words in each set of code mixed sentences.}
\end{table}\
```

Comment: Don't use `p{0.4\linewidth}` for the last column; why should you?

Comment: how should I make it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? How much does it exceed the margins? Maybe you could reduce the white space between columns.

Comment: how can we add a screenshot here ?

Comment: I'll compile your code. You could put the screenshot on some server (imgur) and paste a link. But I'll copy/paste the code you gave.

Comment: <a href="http://imgur.com/2VCqCPm"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2VCqCPm.png?1" title="Hosted by imgur.com" /></a>

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice feature in `tabularx` - you can specify the width of the table. Check the below example (I had to enlarge the first column because the text was overlapping with the second column - so it has a different column descriptor: `>{\arraybackslash\advance\hsize3em}X`:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\arraybackslash\advance\hsize3em}X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X}
\toprule[1.5pt]
& \textbf{Words} & \textbf{En words} & \textbf{Gr words} & \textbf{Al words} & \textbf{\% En words} & \textbf{\% Gr words} &\textbf{\% Al words}\\
\hline
\textbf{Gr/En Mixes} & 3663 & 2207 & 1456 & kati & 60,3 & 39,7 & kati\\
\hline
\textbf{Gr/Al/En Mixes} & 131 & 48 & 51 & 32 & 36,6 & 38,9 & 24,4\\
\hline
\textbf{Gr/Al Mixes} & 35 & kati & 24 & 11 & kati & 68,6 & 31,4\\
\hline
\textbf{Al/En Mixes} & 131 & 72 & kati & 59 & 55,0 & kati & 45,0\\
\hline
\textbf{Total mixes} & 3960 & 2327 & 1531 & 102 & 58,8 & 38,7 & 2,6\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table 6: The percentage of words in each set of code mixed sentences.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: nice one!!  It's perfect now!!1  Thank you very much! so what was I doing wrong ?

Comment: When you use column descriptor `c` the column expands such that the text fits on a single line. If you have many columns with a lot of text, eventually, the table will exceed the margins. If you use `tabularx` with `\textwidth` as the table width and `X` as column descriptor then all columns will have a fixed width (equal to each other) and the cell text will possibly be split on multiple lines.

Comment: Since you're using the `booktabs` package, you may also want to consider (i) getting rid of all vertical rules, (ii) replacing the first `\hline` with `\midrule`, and (iii) getting rid of all other `hline` instructions. Trust me, all those rules won't be missed. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers..!!!  I also applied the tabularx package to a next table and here's what I get [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/zknKgqt.png?1[/IMG]   Why isn't it working this time ?

Comment: Enlarge the columns that don't fit like in the example (where I enlarged only the first column).